# how to reconfigure this dictionary to change its keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have this dictionary:

```
>>> dic = {('a', 'l'):3, ('a', 'p'):2, ('b', 'l'):4, ('b', 'p'):1}
```

How can I edit it so I can have it like this:

```
>>> dic_new = {'a':{'l':3, 'p':2}, 'b':{'l':4, 'p':1}}
```

Whenever I change the keys I get an error. I am confused.

Comment: What have you tried and what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you give us the code used to change the keys and the error it gives you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each case, you want to set `d2[k1][k2]=v` whereever you have `d1[k1,k2]=v`. The simplest way to do this is to start with a defaultdict.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d1 = {('a', 'l'):3, ('a', 'p'):2, ('b', 'l'):4, ('b', 'p'):1}
>>> d2 = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for k1, k2 in d1:
...    d2[k1][k2] = d[k1,k2]
...
>>> d2
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'a': {'l': 3, 'p': 2}, 'b': {'l': 4, 'p': 1}})
>>> dict(d2)
{'a': {'l': 3, 'p': 2}, 'b': {'l': 4, 'p': 1}}
```

If you don't want to use a `defaultdict`, use the `setdefault` method.

```
d2 = {}
for k1, k2 in d1:
    d2.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = d1[k1,k2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the original dictionary and create a new one as you find keys:

```
dic = {('a', 'l'):3, ('a', 'p'):2, ('b', 'l'):4, ('b', 'p'):1}
dic_new = {}
for (new_key, new_sub_key),value in dic.items():
    if new_key not in dic_new:
        dic_new[new_key] = {}
    dic_new[new_key][new_sub_key] = value
print(dic_new)
```

## Output

```
{'a': {'l': 3, 'p': 2}, 'b': {'l': 4, 'p': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` + `OrderedDict`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import OrderedDict

dic = {('a', 'l'):3, ('a', 'p'):2, ('b', 'l'):4, ('b', 'p'):1}

dic = OrderedDict(dic)
new_d = {}

for k, g in groupby(dic, lambda x: x[0]):
    for x in g:
        if k in new_d:
            new_d[k].update({x[1]: dic[x]})
        else:
            new_d[k] = {x[1]: dic[x]}

print(new_d)
# {'a': {'l': 3, 'p': 2}, 'b': {'l': 4, 'p': 1}}
```

Or in case where you can guarantee dictionaries are ordered as per first value in tuple key, you can straightaway ignore `OrderedDict`.